# Help evaluating or upper-bounding integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ab\operatorname{sinc}^2(cx)}{a+b\operatorname{sinc}^2(cx)}\;dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate the following definite integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{ab\operatorname{sinc}^2(cx)}{a+b\operatorname{sinc}^2(cx)}\;dx$$

where $\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is the [Sinc function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc) and $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive constants.  I would also be happy with a reasonably tight upper bound.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: As often happens, the word "solve" is being used here where "evaluate" would be appropriate.  One solves problems; one solves equations; one _evaluates_ expressions.

Comment: Sorry, changed wording of the question accordingly...

Comment: Did you try complex contour integration? maybe some more info on a,b,c would be needed

Comment: @DennisGulko I've never used complex contour integration (and didn't even know that something like that exists before you mentioned it).  Is there a good book/tutorial to get me started?  Also, what kind of info would be needed about $a$, $b$ and $c$?

Comment: @Bullmoose: The lecture notes of William Chen are a good start: http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/wchen/lnicafolder/lnica.html. What you really need is just chapter 11, but, probably, you'll need  the other chapters for background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I an assuming $a,b,c>0$. Let $\delta=\sqrt{b/a}$. Then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{a\,b\,\operatorname{sinc}^2(c\,x)}{a+b\,\operatorname{sinc}^2(c\,x)}\,dx=\frac{b}{c}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2+\delta^2\sin^2x}\,dx=\frac{b}{c}\,I(\delta).
$$
Integrating the inequalities
$$
\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2+\delta^2}\le\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2+\delta^2\sin^2x}\le\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}
$$
we get
$$
\frac{1-e^{-2\delta}}{2\,\delta}\,\pi\le I(\delta)\le\pi.
$$
This bounds are good only for for small $\delta$. For Large $\delta$ try the following:
$$
\begin{align*}
I(\delta)&=2\int_0^\delta\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2+\delta^2\sin^2x}\,dx+2\int_\delta^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2+\delta^2\sin^2x}\,dx\\
&\le\frac{2\,\delta}{1+\delta^2}+2\int_\delta^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\,dx\\
&=\frac{2\,\delta }{\delta ^2+1}+\frac{1-\cos2\,\delta}{\delta}+{\pi -2\,\operatorname{Si}(2\,\delta )},
\end{align*}
$$
where $\operatorname{Si}$ is the [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html). in the graph, $I(\delta)$ is in red and the upper and lower bound in blue.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I've got a question about the upper bound for large $\delta$: could you please elaborate on how $\int_0^\delta\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2+\delta^2\sin^2x}dx\leq\frac{\delta}{1+\delta^2}$?

Comment: $x^2\ge\sin^2x$.